# Let $a=\{a_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that the serie $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}a_nx_n$ condiotionaly convergent for each sequence $x=\{x_n\}\in l_3$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a=\{a_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that the serie $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}a_nx_n$ condiotionaly convergent for each sequence $x=\{x_n\}\in l_3$ Prove that $a\in l^{\frac{3}{2}}$

My attempt:

As the serie $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}a_nx_n$  is conditionaly convergent then 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}a_nx_n$ converge but $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}| a_nx_n|$ diverge.

Note $l_3$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are banach spaces. I want use uniformly bounded theorem for prove $a\in l^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Im stuck trying to prove this.

Comment: The series $\sum_n |a_n x_n|$ does not need to diverge (in fact, if $a\in \ell^{3/2}$, it converges). Try to use the closed graph theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If, as seems clear from something stated in the question, conditionally convergent means "convergent but not absolutely convergent" (as opposed to "not  necessarily
absolutely convergent") then there is no such sequence!

> > **Prop.** Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $\sum a_nb_n$ converges for every $b\in\ell_3$. Then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges absolutely for each $b\in\ell_3$.

Proof: Given $b\in\ell_3$, choose $(\alpha_n)$ so $|\alpha_n|=1$ and $\alpha_n a_nb_n\ge0$ for all $n$.  If $c_n=\alpha_n b_n$ then $c\in\ell_3$; hence $\sum|a_nb_n|=\sum a_nc_n$ converges.

Making it seem likely that the original question was not stated exactly as in the Question above...